# limited include and exclude is not happening through maven compiler plugin

Tags: java, maven

i am using maven compiler plugin of version 3.6.0 , in this we want to compile only one file in a specific folder while it compiles all other files in that location.

for example : in folder app there is 14 files and from that i want only 1 file to compile but it compiles all file and if i want exclude then also it is not working .

```
 <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/../src/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
             <source>1.7</source>
             <target>1.7</target>
             <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
             <includes>
                   <include>app/lable.java</include>
             </includes>
             <excludes>
                   <exclude>app/test.java</exclude>
             </excludes>
        </configuration>
 <execution>
<id>someId</id>
       <goals>
           <goal>compile</goal>
       </goals>
       <phase>compile</phase>
     </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

In this we are using wls maven plugin , is it giving issue ?

Comment: what `mvn` command are you using to execute?

Comment: mvn clean install  ---this is the command

Comment: please update your question with errors faced.

Comment: By your answer i am not facing any error but my pblm is not getting corrected as all files are compiling not as i want only one file among them

Comment: Please update the question with your modified entire `pom.xml` and the commands that you are using to execute.

Comment: updated the question , have a look on that

Comment: complete `pom.xml` please

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [maven-compile-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) -

> The Compiler Plugin has two goals. Both are already bound to their
> proper phases within the Maven Lifecycle and are therefore,
> automatically executed during their respective phases.
>
> **compiler:compile** is bound to the compile phase and is used to compile
> the main source files.
>
> **compiler:testCompile** is bound to the
> test-compile phase and is used to compile the test source files.

So if you use the following command, it should generate the specific target -

```
mvn compiler:compile
```

---

The other way to stick with the `mvn clean install` is to move your configs to an execution defined as -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <includes>
            <include>app/lable.java</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>app/test.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>someId</id>
           <goals>
               <goal>compile</goal>
           </goals>
           <phase>compile</phase>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: showing dependency errors after i have added that  "static import only from classes and interfaces"

Comment: what error, please update the post(edit your question) for any subsequent failures. Also if it is not related to the current context raise another. Multiple questions on one thread is discouraged.

Comment: if i compile using mvn compiler:compile then also all files are compiling not the specific ones which i have given in maven compiler plugins include statement.

Comment: @SidharthRath try the updated answer and if it still doesn't work update the question with complete pom.xml

Comment: after updating  as per you answer , still facing same issue , but main thing i am not getting "static import only from classes and interfaces" --this error